# Jasmine toMatch method not working

Tags: node.js, jasmine

Trying to test time format.

utilities js file:

```
exports.getCurrentTime = function(s) {
    var now = new Date();
    var mins = lzero(now.getMinutes(), 2);
    var dateTime = ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + mins;

    return dateTime;
};
```

Specs class:

```
utilities_spec.js

require("/tijasmine/tijasmine").infect(this);

//create suite, which has a collection of functions for testing
// class or just a slew of functions.
describe("utilities", function() {
    //import utilties class, so that we an access the functions.
    var utilities = require('utilities');

it("Get current time", function() {
    //matcher
    expect(utilities.getCurrentTime()).toMatch('^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$');
});
```

Getting the following error:

```
 utilities Get current time. - Expected ' 23:41' to match '^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$'.
```

How can I pass a regular expression in successfully? If I ignore the quotes at the start end of the regular expression I get compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure what you really want is `/([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/`.

`'([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$'` is a plain string, not a regular expression.